# how to update column values in sql when having " in the string

Tags: sql

I would like to set the value of query column with the following value:

```
call sp_customer('ABC', 'US', 'XYZ', '["1234"]');
SELECT ROUND(gross_profit) as current_gp,
FROM t_CUSTOMER
```

I have written the following update query for the same but it not working and I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near '1234'

```
update TABLE_NAME 
set Query = "call sp_customer('ABC', 'US', 'XYZ', '["1234"]');
SELECT ROUND(gross_profit) as current_gp,
FROM CUSTOMER" where TC_ID = 'TestCaseName' and SubIteration = '11';
```

Please help me with this query.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL uses single quotes for string literals. E.g. `set column = 'some text'`

Comment: And if you need to put a `'` inside your string, double it. E.g. `'Conan O''Brien'`.

Comment: Two options:  Use a framework that allows passing values to SQL statements as parameters.  *(Whatever you are using already probably has "parameterised queries" or "prepared statements" built in, use them...)*  Or learn how to use "escape characters" in both the language you're using and in SQL.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for your help. This is my updated query which is working `update TABLE_NAME 
set Query = 'call sp_customer(''ABC'', ''US'', ''XYZ'', ''["1234"]'');
SELECT ROUND(gross_profit) as current_gp,
FROM CUSTOMER' where TC_ID = 'TestCaseName' and SubIteration = '11';`

Comment: Great! But you should also consider what @MatBailie wrote about parameters.